# django admin grappeli NestedStackedInline loading details with ajax call when expanded?

Tags: ajax, django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I am using [grappelli-nested-inlines](https://github.com/datahub/grappelli-nested-inlines) in my django admin panel, and I would like a bit improve the performance (looking on django debug toolbar's sql queries inspector there are tons of queries done).

Is there some nice way to setup admin clss overriding NestedStackedInline, so that some field will be loaded with extra AJAX call when the stackedinline will be expanded?

Comment: I am having the same issues.

I found that for some choices that were duplicated in the inlines, the same sql query was being called 400-600 times on a single page.  I was able to cache those values, speeding up the page loads a little.  It would be nice to have a way to only load the nested elements once uncollapsed.